# Using Django, How can i check the user is really permitted on updating post

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want update something on the already existing post.

So i used javascript jQuery like this,

```
$('#testButton').click(function () {
   $.ajax({
       url:"/tutomain/detail/1/",
       type:"post",
       data:{
           goingData : 'blah_blah'
       },
       dataType :'json',
   })
});
```

In this case, Even i modify this javascript manually from chrome developers tools(F12 console), the chrome console says like this, and this wouldn't be changed for several post requests.

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:sessionid=sg2l85bxk6z5vkth6gpa; csrftoken=SdNbr42GaSJJCwRMdmTs0F9MeoirDLNY5v2iYk2
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/tutomain/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
X-CSRFToken:SdNbr42GaSJJCwSzsZEXe4XqbFiRMdmTs0F9MeoirDLNY5v2iYk2
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

What i wonder is that,

How can i check the POST request is really validated request, not a maliciously modified, hacked request.

In other words, I want to check whether the user of that 'update request' has been permitted.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for edit,

What i want to know is also like, 'the mechanism of validating specific user or user permission in django'.